# Getting message that "Hold" is not a function in API call

Tags: node.js, express

I have an API (using Node/Express) call that is giving me some trouble. I have a Model I'm referencing like all my other calls, but for some reason, when I try to create an instance of the "Hold" model that you will see in the code below, I get an error saying that {"error":"Hold is not a constructor"}.

Can anyone see why I might be getting this message?

Here is my endpoint:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Card = require('../models/cards');
var Hold = require('../models/hold');
var Profile = require('../models/profile');
var vCard = require('vcards-js');
var GuidGen = require('./helpers/generate_guid');
var sendmail = require('./helpers/post_office');
var constants = require('./helpers/constants');

router.route('/invite')

.post(function( req, res ){

  var hold = new Hold();
  var msgs = '';


// INSERT NEW REQUEST INTO HOLD COLLECTION
  hold.owner_id = req.body.ownerId; 

  //hold.date_invited = Date.now();
  hold.invited_email = req.body.invited_email;
  hold.invited_first_name = req.body.invited_first_name;
  hold.invited_last_name = req.body.invited.last_name;


  hold.status = req.body.status

  hold.first_name = req.body.first_name;
  hold.last_name = req.body.last_name;
  hold.initial = req.body.initial;
  hold.birthday = req.body.birthday;
  hold.highschool = req.body.highschool;
  hold.college = req.body.college;
  hold.facebook = req.body.facebook;
  hold.linkedin = req.body.linkedin;
  hold.user_image = req.body.user_image;

  hold.phones = req.body.phones;
  hold.emails = req.body.emails;
  hold.addresses = req.body.addresses;
  hold.businesses = req.body.businesses;

  hold.save(function(err){
    if(err)
      res.send('First Error Point' + err);  
    //res.json(hold);
    msgs = 'INSERT NEW REQUEST INTO HOLD COLLECTION - success; ';
  });
```

Comment: Uhhh, we would have to see the `'../models/hold'` code to know what the issue is with `Hold()`.  Did you try a `console.log(Hold)` and `console.log(typeof Hold)` to see what it actually is. My guess is that you are not doing the export right in the hold module and not exporting a constructor properly.

Answer (score 0):

jfriend00 was right. The problem was that I was  not exporting a constructor properly.